# Undefined Route

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to laravel and I am really terrible with routing. I want to delete the specific data but it say that route is undefined

**CandidateController.php**
*this is my method to delete*

```
public function destroy(Form $candidates)
{
    $candidates->delete();

    return redirect()->route('candidate.approve');
}
```

**route**

```
Route::resource('candidates', CandidateController::class);
```

I am using a resourse, when I go through the tutorial, it shortened my code into above. When I clicked the button delete, it says that Undefined route [candidate.approve]. Can someone help me where I went wrong?

**blade**

```
 @foreach ($candidates as $candidate)
                            <div class="modal__content">
                                <div class="p-5 text-center"> <i data-feather="x-circle" class="w-16 h-16 text-theme-6 mx-auto mt-3"></i>
                                    <form action="{{ route('candidates.destroy', $candidate->id) }}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <div class="text-3xl mt-5">Are you sure?</div>
                                        <div class="text-gray-600 mt-2">Do you really want to delete these records? This process cannot be undone.</div>

                                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="button w-24 border text-gray-700 dark:border-dark-5 dark:text-gray-300 mr-1">Cancel</button> 
                                        <button type="submit" title="delete" class="button w-24 bg-theme-6 text-white" >Delete</button> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="px-5 pb-8 text-center"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('application/approve/{id}', 'CandidateController@postApprove')->name('application');
Route::get('candidate', [CandidateController::class, 'approve'])->name('candidate.approve');
Route::resource('candidates', CandidateController::class);
```

Comment: This is most probably because of there is no actual route defined `candidate.approve` in your web.php file. When you specify the route name. Check your routes with `php artisan route:list` and you get all the routes

Comment: Your destroy route would be `candidates.destroy` [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Comment: @Tithira I follow the documentation but it says *Missing required parameters for [Route: candidates.destroy] [URI: candidates/{candidate}]*

Comment: Yes, you will need to pass the parameter for the route, which is the `primary key` or your model. By default `id` is the primary key. Destroy method accepts the primary key in your controller function and returns an instance, therefore pass the route parameters `{{ route('candidates.destroy', ['candidate' => $candidate->id]) }}` in your action trigger [Passing parameters for routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Comment: actually I've put the id inside my action trigger but still not working

Comment: did you setup in an array ? Change this `{{ route('candidates.destroy', $candidate->id) }}` to this `{{ route('candidates.destroy', ['candidate' => $candidate->id]) }}`

Comment: yes I changed as per your suggestion, but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add new Route with **candidate.approve** name before Route::resource.

your web.php file will be like this

```
Route::get('your-url', [CandidateController::class, 'approve')->name('candidate.approve');
Route::resource('candidates', CandidateController::class);
```

But its better to use prural for named route, like the resource controller :

1. candidates.create
2. candidates.store
3. ...

**UPDATE**

Since i know the flow of the app, you should use this on controller:

```
return back();
```

Why? because when admin click Delete on modal, it will goes to another URL to delete data from DB. After delete, return back() will redirect admin to previous URL

Comment: I tried but still the route is undefined :((

Comment: show us your web.php content. Also check your blade (idk either <a> tag with href=route('candidate.approve')

Comment: I update my question which include blade and web.php

Comment: What's the flow after user delete the candidates? maybe it helps me to improve my answer

Comment: it will return to the same blade. let say my blade is showing a candidate list then admin click on Candidate A "delete" button, it will appear a pop up confirmation then after admin click delete, it will redirect to the same blade but Candidate A is not there anymore

Comment: Check my answer, hope it helps. Also check any blade files which call candidate.approve. If you see that, just delete it to prevent error